# Buttons not showing up when coding in Python

Tags: python, class, button, tkinter

I'm currently learning Python through videos online. I was working on this piece of code when I encountered a problem: no buttons show up. It seems to work fine for the guy in the video so I'm wondering what I'm doing wrong.

Please keep in mind that this is from a video tutorial and hence the code may not be that great.

I'm using PyCharm Community Edition 2017.2.

```
from tkinter import *


class Application(Frame):
    def ___init___(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.button1 = Button(self)
        self.button1.grid()
        self.button1.configure(text="Button1")
        self.button2 = Button(self, text="Button 2")
        self.button2.grid()
        self.button3 = Button(self, text="Button 3")
        self.button3.grid()

root = Tk()
root.title("Something")
root.geometry("200x100")

app = Application(root)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a wrong `__init__` function, it takes only 2 underscores before/after :

```
class Application(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()
```

Comment: @IbrahimPelja Please Accept His Answer By Pressing the Little Tick Next to It. This Way He Can Get Reputation